# Retrieving distinct values in rows and counting total

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, distinct-values

just looking for any info on my problem, not necessarily the exact answer.

I have a table called WorkDay.

In the Workday Table, there are 6 fields:

```
Date_of_Workday, Workday_type, Boss, Regular, Tech1, Tech2.
```

Employees can be assigned multiple roles and there are also a few fields which are NULL.

I want to write a query that will return the total number of employees assigned to each workday, but obviously if there is an employee assigned to the Boss role and also to the Tech2 role, that will only count as one employee.

EDIT:
This is my desired output.

```
+------------+------------+----+
|Date_of_Work| Work_type  |    |
+------------+------------+----+
| 2019-02-09 | AM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-09 | PM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-10 | AM         |  3 |
| 2019-02-10 | PM         |  2 |
| 2019-02-11 | AM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-11 | PM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-12 | AM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-12 | PM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-13 | AM         |  4 |
| 2019-02-13 | PM         |  4 |
 ------------+------------+----
```

This is SELECT * FROM Workday:

```
+------------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| DateofWork | workday_typ | Boss   | Regular  |   Tech1   |   Tech2   |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-02-09 | AM         | LB1     | AW1      | AE1       | JE1       |
| 2019-02-09 | PM         | AE1     | IM1      | AL1       | BJ1       |
| 2019-02-10 | AM         | AE1     | MM1      | MW1       | NULL      |
| 2019-02-10 | PM         | AE1     | AE1      | EB1       | NULL      |
| 2019-02-11 | AM         | LB1     | AB1      | DJ1       | JP1       |
| 2019-02-11 | PM         | LB1     | JE1      | AB2       | BJ1       |
| 2019-02-12 | AM         | LB1     | NS1      | AE1       | MB1       |
| 2019-02-12 | PM         | LB1     | HP1      | EH1       | AL1       |
| 2019-02-13 | AM         | LB1     | EB2      | ME1       | MM1       |
| 2019-02-13 | PM         | LB1     | ME2      | AB2       | DJ1       |
+------------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am unsure as to go about this query. Any information/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet to get this going?

Comment: It might help if you provide a sample of the table contents. What appears in those fields? True and false? Is there also an employees table that links to the workday table? We need more details of the relevant tables in your database.

Comment: The WorkDay table has an Employees table that is linked to it. The PK is Employee_Code which is the FK on the Boss, Regular, Tech1 and Tech2 fields in the WorkDay table.  Each Employee has an employee code, basically their initials with a number. I can easily get the output to display the DISTINCT COUNT for each column, such as the unique values in manager column etc, but I can't count each individual row and total them up.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output. That'll be really helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple Boss or tech1 or tech2 for same WorkDay?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor (denormalised) table design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your woefully denormalized table has mutiple columns containing peoples's names. You want to count the number of unique values in all these columns for each day, it seems.

Try something like this to get the unique values on each day. This gives back a result set with `Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Person` as columns. The use of `UNION` eliminates duplicate `Person` values.

```
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Boss AS Person FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type,  Regular AS Person  FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Tech1 AS Person FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Tech2 AS Person FROM tbl
```

Then use that subquery in an aggregate query like this: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1320a/1/0)

```
SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, COUNT(Person) AS PersonCount
  FROM (
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Boss AS Person FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type,  Regular AS Person  FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Tech1 AS Person FROM tbl
          UNION 
          SELECT Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type, Tech2 AS Person FROM tbl
       ) Persons
 GROUP BY Date_of_Workday, Workday_Type
```

You need `COUNT(Person)` instead of `COUNT(*)` here, otherwise it will count `NULL` values and therefore overcount people.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked like a charm. Can I just ask: how does MySQL know what Persons is? There is no defining of it, or anything. As far as I can see, in this example you have put SELECT (fields) FROM (arguments) Persons. It works, but I'm not sure what the Persons is.

Comment: `Persons` is an alias for the subquery, declared right after the close parenthesis. When you say `SELECT FROM (some sub query ) Alias` you have to give the sub query a `Alias` name or SQL won't take it. You could use any name you like.

Comment: You've used `union` in subquery so it'll automatically remove duplicate row when an employee assign as both boss & tech 1. Am I right?

Comment: @Harshil exactly right. `UNION` is a set thing.  `UNION ALL` would refrain from deduplicating the set.